# novalidate with error ora-02299

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

can anybody help with me with this?

```
id | Name
--------
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
3  | aaa

>alter table arc add CONSTRAINT uk_arc UNIQUE (NAME) novalidate
 error :ora-02299: cannot validate( .uk_arc ) - duplicate keys found
```

I am using novalidate to ignore the old duplicate and start to validate all over again.

Comment: Possible explanation [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8806498660292)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you expect Oracle to ignore old duplicate values and allow new values only when they satisfy the constraint. The error is returned because when you add a `UNIQUE` constraint, Oracle creates unique index on the column to check the values, but your table already have duplicate values, so it fails. I would create the non-unique index first, then add the constraint so that it uses your existing non-unique index instead of automatically creating the unique index which would fail:

```
create index arc_ix on arc (name);

alter table arc add constraint arc_uq unique (name) enable novalidate;
```

Comment: yes I did that now, But why it will works on the non unique index ? can you explain please ?

Comment: To guarantee uniqueness required by `UNIQUE` constraint, Oracle needs index, and by default it creates unique index if you add `UNIQUE` constraint. Unique index alone can guarantee uniqueness, and that way `UNIQUE` constraint is redundant. So the `UNIQUE` constraint in this case is more like a declarative way to say that there's some constraint. Non-unique index, on the other hand, allows duplicates (hence the name), and can serve for the `UNIQUE` constraint as the means to determine if there are duplicate values. In this case the constraint is not declarative.

Comment: works for me, thanks!

Comment: But it doesn't work for me when I execute the second query I get ORA-02299: cannot validate (...) - duplicate keys found Position: 42

Comment: @majid_shoorabi Does dropping the existing index and re-creating a new one along with a constraint as suggested in the answer help?