# Alter table enable novalidate constraint

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to add `UNIQUE KEY` on a previously existing table with duplicate records by setting `ENABLE NOVALIDATE`.

But I am getting `ORA-02299: cannot validate (my_owner.my_key_UK ) - duplicate keys found`

```
ALTER TABLE my_owner.my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_key_UK UNIQUE (ID1,ID2)
ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [novalidate with error ora-02299](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163580/novalidate-with-error-ora-02299)

Answer (score 7):

A unique constraint uses an index to enforce the noduplicates rule. By default it will create a unique index (makes sense right?). It is this index creation which is hurling `ORA-02299`.

However, if this is an existing index on the constrained columns the constraint will use that. The good news is, the index doesn't need to be unique for the constraint to use it.

So what you need to do is build a non-unique index first:

```
create index whatever_idx on my_table (ID1,ID2);
```

Then you will be able to create your constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE my_owner.my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_key_UK UNIQUE (ID1,ID2)
ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

You can check this by querying the data dictionary:

```
select uc.constraint_name
       , uc.constraint_type
       , uc.index_name
       , ui.uniqueness as idx_uniqueness
from user_constraints uc
     join user_indexes ui
          on ui.index_name = uc.index_name
where uc.table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ensure unique values using indexes. And if you create unique constrains db automatic creates unique index. Workaround is add `DEFERRABLE`  options. In this case oracle creates normal index. Check example.

```
create table table_abc (a number,b number);

insert into table_abc values(1,1);
insert into table_abc values(1,2);

ALTER TABLE table_abc ADD CONSTRAINT my_key_a UNIQUE (a) DEFERRABLE enable novalidate; -- no error but in table nonunique values
ALTER TABLE table_abc ADD CONSTRAINT my_key_b UNIQUE (b) ENABLE NOVALIDATE; --no error 

select * from user_indexes where table_name ='TABLE_ABC';
```

Comment: Deferrable is a neat trick but it does change the behavior of the constraint, which may have undesirable side-effects.

Comment: am having around 10 lakhs of data which is having many duplicate. My requirement is that the new data which will be inserted should have uniqueness. So can you please explain what behavioural changes may happen to the constraint if DEFERRABLE is used?

Comment: @APC what side effect?

Comment: @Neeraj `DEFERRABLE` works as normal constraints if you don't change nothing. If you excute `SET CONSTRAINTS my_key a DEFERRED` constraint will be checked during the commit.

Comment: @Neeraj If you drop `DEFERRABLE` constrains oracle dosen't drop background index automatically.

Comment: @Arkadiusz - if I am not setting it as DEFERRED it will normally behave as NOT DEFERRABLE so my scenario should work fine right?

Comment: @Neeraj IMHO, yes

Comment: @APC ,@Arkadiusz
Really appreciate the way you people  helped, Thanks Guys :D